# Sharepoint Active Directory Import importing users from unselected OU

Tags: sharepoint-server, active-directory, active-directory-import

I have Sharepoint Active Directory Import running pulling users from AD. I have distribution lists, security groups and 2 (of 4) user groups selected to import. The remaining 2 OU's I do not have selected as I do not want them to be imported.

The import still brings in new users created in the OU's NOT selected. It does not bring in old users I have already deleted from Sharepoint but any new ones created, it still imports them even though I have explicitly deselected them in the OU.

There are 3 other accounts in an unselected OU that continue to be imported but most do not.

Why are these accounts still being imported even though the OU is not selected in the import settings?

Comment: Are the users in that unselected OU visiting a SharePoint site on the farm?

Comment: They may be but I don't need them to. They may be in security groups that I'm importing if that makes a difference.

Answer (score 1):

I've sorted this one out. I'll leave this here in case it helps someone else. The import is set up correctly. What's happening is that when users that don't have a profile created during the import view Sharepoint it creates a profile for them automatically. These are then imported into the people search where we don't want to see them.